# Proper way to return a mutation result? (GraphQL with Apollo and Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

I was able to get something returned from `updateTopic` with the following code

```
    Mutation: {
        async updateTopic(parent, args, context, info) {
            const { _id, name, desc, body, subject } = args
            r = await Topic.findOneAndUpdate({_id: _id}, {$set:{ name:name, desc:desc, body:body, subject:subject}}, {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}, (err, topic) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    return err
                } else {
                    console.log(topic)
                    return { ...topic._doc }
                }
            })
            return r
        },
```

It seems a bit weird to me that I need an `async` function and `await` in order to get this to work but for my function `addTopic` I was able to do it without this.

Am I doing this the best way or is there a better way with Apollo-Server and Mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a Promise and avoid async and await, generally all queries and mutations usually return Promises.

```
  Mutation: {
    updateTopic(parent, args, context, info) {
        const { _id, name, desc, body, subject } = args
        return Topic.findOneAndUpdate({_id: _id}, {$set:{ name:name, desc:desc, body:body, subject:subject}}, {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}, (err, topic) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err)
                return err
            } else {
                console.log(topic)
                return { ...topic._doc }
            }
        })
    },
```

It's always a good idea to put logic of a query/mutation into separate file (service).